# Jquery Ajax in CodeIgniter- always success

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('.messagebox button').click(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo confi_item('base_url').'index.php/users/savemesage'?>",
       success: function(){
                alert("sucess");
       } 
    });
 });
```

Why it keeps on prompting "success" even if I mean to make it wrong ?(this is to test whether it successfully go to the controller)-- like getting "g" in (config_item).it seems like it's ignoring it. it keeps on alerting . Can you help me ?

Comment: Change `savemesage` to `undefinedmessage` then check

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
jQuery('.messagebox button').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo confi_item('base_url').'index.php/users/savemesage'?>",
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data){
                 alert(data);
                }
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get error for `page not found` try,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo confi_item('base_url').'index.php/users/savemesage'?>",
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
           alert( "page not found" );
        }
    },
    success: function(){
       alert("sucess");
    } 
});
```

See **[jquery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** and if you see in `console` then `ci` automatically use `base_url()`, then your string which you used after `base_url()`

Or you can use **[ajaxError()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)**

Comment: I updated my code with yours .but doesn't but nothing happened it's not prompting anything. but when I replace your "$.ajax" to "jQuery.ajax" then it prompts the "sucess" . does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, it matters when you are using `multiple libraries` so there may be `conflictions` use `jQuery.noConflict();` or you can use `jQuery` in place of `$`